# How to add a Map<String, List<String>> in an entity class?

Tags: java, oracle, jpa, jpa-2.0, eclipselink

I would like to add a mapping like

```
Map<String, List<String>> attributes;
```

I have used already `@MapKeyColumn` for other situation, but here I do have a key/value table where a key might occur several time.

How would you solve this? Is there any (JPA built-in) solution for that kind of problem domain?

Thank you for your response!

Comment: If you don't find any solution, just make a custom class, which has the attributes "name" and "List<String>"

Comment: Thank you :-) I do have a custom class which represent an attribute. It's a list of these objects within my entity. A Map would just be more convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way.  You need to create a class to represent the association or perform some sort of conversion in get/set methods.

See,

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Nested_Collections.2C_Maps_and_Matrices

Comment: Thank you James! Great source.